# waiting for async operations in angular

Tags: angular, jhipster

In the following code snippet, how can I wait for the async operations to complete and then execute the loop?

```
ngOnInit() {
       this.userService.query()
        .subscribe((res: HttpResponse<User[]>) => { this.users = res.body; }, (res: HttpErrorResponse) => this.onError(res.message));

    this.principal.identity().then((account) => {
        this.currentAccount = account;

    });

    //my loop 
    for ( const user of this.users){
        if (user.login === this.currentAccount.login){
            this.currentUserId = user.id;
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: you can used promise http://www.gistia.com/mastering-promises/

Answer (score 1):

Change either the promise to Observable, or the Observable to promise, resolve them all, then run the loop.

```js
const c1 = this.userService.query().toPromise();
const c2 = this.principal.identity();
Promise.all([c1, c2]).then(([r1, r2]) => {
  for (...)
})

const c1 = this.userService.query();
const c2 = Observable.fromPromise(this.principal.identity());
Observable.forkJoin([c1, c2]).subscribe([r1, r2] => {
  for(...)
});
```

Comment: Considering the first case, it seems that then() cannot accept an array, as parameter and gives error. Sorry, I'm new to javascript. Would you complete your code?

Comment: My bad, syntax error. Surround the array with parenthesis, and you should be good. I edited my answer.